# Vuejs 3 loop without using a query

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, vue.js

I am using vue.js version 3, I don't understand how I can retrieve data with a loop when I use a query. I try to retrieve an object by its id but I can't.I get the id in the url. Who can tell me what I did wrong.Thank you

vue routing

```
{
    path:'/faq/:idQuestions',
    name:'FaqQuestion',
    component:() => import('../components/admin/faq/FaqQuestion.vue')
},
```

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h2 class="title-faq">Questions fréquentes</h2>
        <div class="list-faq">
            <router-link @click="getQuestion" class="link-vehicule" :to=" 
  {name:'FaqQuestion', params:{idQuestions:1}}"><p class="list-faq_question">test 1</p></router-link>
            <router-link class="link-vehicule" :to="{name:'FaqQuestion', params:{idQuestions:2}}"><p class="list-faq_question">test 2</p></router-link>
            <router-link class="link-vehicule" :to="{name:'FaqQuestion', params:{idQuestions:3}}"><p class="list-faq_question">test 3</p></router-link>
```

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="faq in faqQuestion" :key="faq.id">
                <p>{{faq.id }}</p>
                <h1 >{{ faq.title }}</h1>
                <p>{{ faq.question }}</p>  
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name:"FaqQuestion",
    data(){
        return{
            idTest: 2,
            question:[],
            //id:2,
            faqQuestion:[
              {
                        id: 1,
                        title:"New-title-1",
                        question: "test 1"               
                },
                {              
                        id:2,
                        title:"new-title 2",
                        question: "test 2"              
                },
                {   
                        id:3,
                        title:"new title 3",
                        question: "test 3"        
                }
            ]
        }
    },
   beforeMount(){
         const url = window.location.href;
        this.id = url.split("/").slice(-1)[0];
       console.log(this.id)
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please show how your URL looks like in full with the id

Comment: Here is the url @Kevin, I clicked on the first link which at id: 1.http://localhost:8080/faq/1

Comment: Are you using Vue-router?

Comment: How are you doing the routing? Please create a [mcve]

Comment: I am using vue router, I modified and I put the routing code in my description

Answer (score 1):

You can access the route param in your template like this:

```
{$route.params.idQuestions}
```

Or using `this.$route.params.idQuestions` inside component methods.

You can find specific data based on it using `Array.find()` like:

```
this.faqQuestion.find(question => question.id == this.$route.params.idQuestions )
```

Comment: Thank you TJ for your answer, I manage to retrieve the url parameter. What I can't do is just get the object that matches the id that is in the url. When I arrive on the page it displays all the objects of the table even if in the url it is written id: 1 or 2 or 3

Comment: @tony updated the answer (not sure if data would be present in `beforeMount`, make sure it is)

Comment: thank you for your help it works I manage to recover a single object. You can tell me how to not display it as an object : it displays like this {"id":1, "title":new-title-1, "question":test1}

Comment: Could you update the question or link to a new one with your current setup? I think this is caused by something not shown in the question

Comment: I succeeded thank you again for your help :)